# Convert.ToDecimal throws "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format" inside dotnet core docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, cultureinfo

I'm trying to convert a negative string to a decimal with this line of code in a dotnet docker container.

```
var foo = Convert.ToDecimal("-1 097,42");
```

Locally I get -1097,42 as expected. But when I run the code in a dotnet container I get:

```
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at System.Number.ParseDecimal(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles styles, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value)
```

I've tried to disable by setting DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false. [To disable Invariant culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/globalization)

I've tried to provide culture info into Convert.ToDecimal:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
var foo = Convert.ToDecimal("-1 097,42", culture);
```

I've tried to set CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture like this:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture.
```

I've also tried:

```
var foo = decimal.Parse("-1 097,42", NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, cultureInfo);
```

But neither solves my problems. I still get the same error. You can find a small example [in this git repo](https://github.com/Lundbyit/culture-issue)

Build the docker image and try to run it.

I would be very thankful for any help

Comment: Why do you have a space after the one?

Comment: It's the thousand separator in the culture(sv-SE).

Comment: It works on my computer.  Try copying the culture and foo from this posting and put into VS and see if it works.  There may be an encoding issue.  Then take string from good and bad code and run following :  byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("-1 097,42");

Comment: It works on my machine, the issue is when I try to run it in a dotnet core docker container. 
If you download the small example I provided, build the docker image and try to run the image it doesn't work. 

Thanks for the tips. If it is bad encoding you suspect it will throw an exception?

Comment: I tried:
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("-1 097,42");

It works fine, both locally and in a docker container

Comment: But do the bytes match you original that fails.  I think you have a unicode space in your original code that fails.  The byte array should show a difference between working and non working string to bytes.

Comment: I tried it now and it is the same bytes.

Comment: What changed so it is now working?

Comment: The bytes are all the same, but the conversion still fails when I run it in the container.

Comment: You may be running a different version of ToDecimal.  I would right click ToDecimal and select defination and see why it is defined.  Also Culture.  If you look at the culture variable culture.NumberFormat you should see all the properties. The Group Property should be a space.

Comment: Do you mean that it is different ToDecimal in the container and locally on my machine? I checked and it is defined in the namespace System, in static class Convert. So System.Convert.ToDecimal.
I checked the NumberFormat NumberGroupSeparator and CurrencyGroupSeparator. It is the same in the docker container and locally. It is a space.

Comment: I can't explain why you are getting the error.  Did you rebuild docker using clean build?

Comment: yes, tried several times. Thanks for your help. Does it work for you when you build and run the container?

Comment: I don't have docker installed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

An exception is thrown because there is a space in the string you want to parse.

Solution 1 - Replace Method

```
string noSpaceString = spaceString.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
```

Solution 2 - Regex

```
string noSpaceString = Regex.Replace(spaceString, @"\s", "");
```

After using one of the following methods, you can call a method that parses a string to a floating point type.

Also pay attention to whether the part of the number after the decimal point is separated by a point or a comma. Based on this, the appropriate:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo
```

option must be selected.

Comment: hmm, it works on when I run it on my machine but not in a docker container.
I tried to run 
var culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
var foo = Convert.ToDecimal("-1097,42", culture);
in a docker container and it still doesn't work

Comment: I think the problem may be caused by the difference between cultures on Windows and Linux, maybe this article by Andrew Lock will help you with your problem: https://andrewlock.net/dotnet-core-docker-and-cultures-solving-culture-issues-porting-a-net-core-app-from-windows-to-linux/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into how to install ICU-libs into my dotnet container.